# Track by color with kinect and c#

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect, color-tracking

I have a problem with my latest project, I'm new to kinect and my programming skills are not excellent. 
I need my program to detect my stick (by color), so I can make a lasergun (red line comming out of the stick on my computer) with it. 
I'm having a lot of troubles with this color tracking. This far I have the following code:

```
private void zoekGekleurdeStok(Image<Bgr, Byte> openCVImg)
    {
        pxLock img = new pxLock();

        Bitmap b = BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(colorBitmap);
        DataTable pxLocation = img.GetPixelLocation(b, c);


        if (pxLocation.Rows.Count <= 0) { return; }
        //Setup Rectangle
        int boxWidth = 20;
        int boxHeight = 20;
        //Get Pixel Position
        int iX = Convert.ToInt32(pxLocation.Rows[0]["Column"]);
        int iY = Convert.ToInt32(pxLocation.Rows[0]["Row"]);

        //Configure Rectangle
        //System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(iX, iY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(iX, iY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
        //Configure Pen Style
        System.Drawing.Pen RedPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2);
        RedPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
        //Draw Rectangle
        //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(RedPen, rect); /  /e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);

        System.Drawing.Point p3 = new System.Drawing.Point();
        p3.X = iX;
        p3.Y = iY;


        System.Drawing.Point p4 = new System.Drawing.Point();

        p4.X = iX + 30;
        p4.Y = iY + 30;
        LineSegment2D line = new LineSegment2D();
        line.P1 = p3;
        line.P2 = p4;


        openCVImg.Draw(line, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Red), 5);
    }
```

But I believe that it takes to long to fill in my pxLocation, and the sub is called time after time.
After days of not producing any good code I'm thinking I should switch to a different language or programma?

Perhaps anybody here, has experience with this. I just want to make a simple color tracking program with my kinect.

I hope you guys understand my explenation, my English isn't very well. I'm sorry for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Are you getting any errors or it just doesn't work?

Comment: When I don't use the function, my kinect image/video is shown. But when I use the code, the image is just gray.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the HAND co-ordinates provided in Microsoft Kinect SDK for stick's location (or tracking) and try doing the colour search or whatever else you would like to do.

Comment: The hand coordinates aren't exact enough, my laserline needs to come out the stick exactly in the direction I'm holding it. I'm trying to detect by color but it doesn't work. If anybody please can help me!